# What is my phone's version name?

Tags: 8.1

My phone's current version is **8.10.14234.375**. Does this version have a specific name?

Comment: WP8.1 does not really have names of its updates afaik. The Lumia phones do have additional names like "Cyan" - you can find this name in the settings (I think under info or extras).

Answer (score 3):

"Denim" was the codename for a Nokia specific update of Windows Phone 8.1 that brought GDR1 and a few Nokia specific features.

8.10.14234.375 is an update that came (a fair while) [after the Denim update](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Phone_version_history)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Phone_version_history#Windows_Phone_8.1) the codename is **GDR1**. The official name is **Denim**.

Comment: Strictly speaking GDR1 was the Microsoft half of the update (also delivered to HTC handsets, for example), Whilst Denim was the Nokia update that included GDR1.

Comment: Right, thanks for the info. Didn't know that.